# Change size of view

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I put a button on view and want to call this view from another view and change size of this view but when i change size,size of button doesn't change How can i change size of view that size of all controls on view changed?

```
Three *second = [[Three alloc] initWithNibName:@"Three" bundle:nil];
 second.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
 [self.view addSubview:second.view];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the time comes to change the size of the view, at the following code.

```
second.view.frame = CGRectMake(a,b,c,d);
```

Where a, b, c, and d are integers.

Answer (score 1):

Set the frame for the view in the Interface Builder, you're using a nib anyway.
But I think it's really strange what you made. You create a UIViewController and set the view of this controller as a subview of another controller's view. Why don't you directly compose that view in the same nib?

Comment: I want to resize view beacuse i want to add 4 views in this view and i should resize them

Comment: Well, set the UIView as a IBOutlet, then set up the whole view in Interface builder, and then (at runtime) you add it as a subview and resize the view by setting a new frame.